# How to deal with constant data stream(from twitter)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter

Im trying to display these tweets coming from the stream to the browser with rails

Where would I handle the constant stream in the controller?

```
 TweetStream.track('happy') do |status|

     temp = status.text

     if(temp.include? "http")
         puts "#{status.text}"
     end
 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at pusherapp (https://github.com/pusher/pusher-gem).

this enables you to have a websocket open and transfer data from a background task in your rails app to your javascript client app.